# Identify phone number in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

i am using the following code to detect if a string is a phone number...

```
<?php
$text = "example467676@gmail.com" ;
if (preg_match_all('/\+?[0-9][0-9()-\s+]{4,20}[0-9]/',$text)){
    echo "phone number";    
}else{
    echo "not a phone number";
}
?>
```

the problem is that i get `phone number` where as i should be getting `not a phone number`... how can i solve this problem... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to check if someone has used a phone number in their email address? That's not gonna work too well.

Comment: i mean phone number instead of an email address...

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357675/validating-us-phone-number-with-php-regex

Comment: What if someone had an email address as `peterpan201344

Comment: yeah that's the problem.. @AmalMurali

Comment: Instead of looking for something that looks like a phone number, wouldn't it be easier to check for something that doesn't look like an email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `{4,20}` will match any string in which the preceding block appears 4 to 20 times, so it matches the digits in the sample email address.  Try this:

```
<?php
$text = "example467676@gmail.com" ;
if (preg_match_all('/^\+?([0-9-]|\s|\([0-9]+\)){4,20}[0-9]/',$text)){
    echo "phone number";    
}else{
    echo "not a phone number";
}
?>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/uGKtpKbIvUrgvspk)

[Note that `preg_match_all` requires 3 parameters in PHP < 5.4](http://php.net/preg_match_all).

Comment: your code works fine but the problem is i get not a phone number when i put in this +8801689347804

Comment: That's because I didn't know you wanted to match `+` signs. I've updated it to match an optional `+` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

[`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) starts from the first match until the last one.

In this case the first match would be `4`, and it continues till `6`. Ignoring all the other characters.

To make it start from the beginning use `^` (**beginning of line anchor**) before the regular expression. And to force it to continue until the end put `$` (**end of line anchor**) at the end of the regular expression.

Like this:

```
<?php
$text = "example467676@gmail.com" ;
if (preg_match_all('/^+?[0-9][0-9()-\s+]{4,20}[0-9]/$', $text)) {
  echo "phone number";  
} else{
  echo "not a phone number";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the regular expression you've got in your example is returning a match even when someone puts in an email address with numbers, like you have there.

Match to the beginning and end of the line *only* to avoid this, using `^` and `$`:

```
<?php
$text = "example467676@gmail.com" ;
if (preg_match_all('^/\+?[0-9][0-9()-\s+]{4,20}[0-9]$/',$text)){
    echo "phone number";    
}else{
    echo "not a phone number";
}
?>
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/xY0yU3